# Hyphen within string in mysql query causing strange behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

In my Rails testing environment, I have a `user_id` that looks like `1234-567abc89`. I'm getting inconsistent behaviour by querying this user in different tables. Most of the queries are working, but running one particular query fails:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column '1234' in 
'where clause': SELECT * FROM `point_allocations` WHERE (user_id = 1234-567abc89) ):
```

So for some reason, everything beyond the hyphen is getting cut off. I realized that for the queries that work, it is looking up user `1234` instead of `1234-567abc89`, but if all the others work, any idea why only this one would return an error?

Comment: add quotes around your string '1234-567abc89'?

Comment: why is your user_id alphanumeric? *cry*

Comment: What is the column spec for user_id in the database? varchar(255)? Integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include quotations.

```
SELECT * FROM `point_allocations` WHERE (user_id = '1234-567abc89')
```

Because the `user_id` column expects character-typed data, it will take your value (1234-567abc89) and parse it as an integer, truncating the content after the hyphen. If you include it in quotations, it will accept it as a string and transfer properly.

Enjoy and good luck!